# Wiremock verify multiple requests

Tags: java, wiremock

I've recently started using Wiremock and am working on extending a project that's using it to verify XML request bodies.
In the current format an assertion would like this:

```
                    verify(postRequestedFor(urlEqualTo('/Register'))
                            .withRequestBody(matching('.*<FirstName>Johnny</FirstName>.*'))
                            .withRequestBody(matching('.*<MiddleName>Be</MiddleName>.*'))
                            .withRequestBody(matching('.*<LastName>Good</LastName>.*'))
```

What I want to know is if it's possible to create a method that can dynamically build the parameters to match? I want to achieve something like this:

```
public void verifyRequestBody(String url, List <String> requestBodyParts){
    verify(postRequestedFor(urlEqualTo(url))
            // for (String body: requestBodyParts){
                // add  .withRequestBody(matching(body))

}
```

I thought of doing this, but I'm thinking it would cause performance issues?

```
   public void verifyRequestBody(String url, List <String> requestBodyParts){

    for (String body: requestBodyParts){
        verify(postRequestedFor(urlEqualTo(url))
                .withRequestBody(matching(body)))
    }
}
```

Is the best solution just to create a separate method for each assertion?